# VBA Nested If Multiple docs

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, nested

Okay so I feel like I'm close in my coding however I'm not quite there.

What I want to do is have excel look at workbook A in column B.offset(0, 3) and for each value that is = "RF" I want it to check if the value in workbook B in column B.offset(0, 3) = "RF"
.
If the workbook B value is not "RF" I want to have the value in workbook A column B of each instance to be pasted into workbook C in the same destination (ex: b4 to b4)

If the workbook B value is "RF" I want excel to look at the value in column B.offset(0, 11) For workbook A and B. for each instance where workbook A column B.offset(0, 11) > workbook B column B.offset(0, 11) I want to post the value of workbook A column B into the same destination. (I didn't start this second part as the code was already messing up but below is my code)

Please let me know if you need any more info and thanks for the Help. (took my code out cause it wasn't posting hope this works)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding the organization of your data.  In Excel terms, WorkBook is a collection of worksheets and exists as an Excel File.  I am assuming you are using three Excel files.  Your use of offset isn't matching the syntax of offset(range, row, col).  Are you performing this set of evaluations on each row of data - using WorkBook A, column B as the master?
Here's the algorithm as I understand it:

```
For each row in WorkbookA.ColB(offset 3) 
    if workbookA.colB(offset 3).value = "RF" then
       If workbookB.colB(offset 3).value <> "RF" then
           workbookC.colB(offset 3).value = workbookA.colB(offset 3).value
       ELSE
           Avar = workbookA.colB(offset 11).value
           Bvar = workbookB.colB(offset 11).value
           if Avar > Bvar Then
               workbookC.colB(offset 11).value = Avar
           End if
       end if
    end if
Next row
```

So workbook C has the possibility of getting 0-1 columns updated per row.  With 3 workbooks/files, I would put the code in WorkBook A.  Capture the row,  col3Data, and col 11 Data from Workbook A into a User-Defined-Type array where the row corresponds to the array index.  The structure would include Acol3Data, Acol11Data, Bcol3Data, Bcol11Data.
Once you load the Worksheet A data into the Array, Open an Excel object on WorkBook B, use the index of the array to load Bcol3Data and Bcol11Data.  Close WorkBook B.  Open Workbook C.  Start at the top of your array and work through the algorithm for each index value.  You will have an easier time using objSheet.cells(i,3).value instead of the offset statement.  i is the row, 3 is the column.

Comment: Using your code I'm still getting the same issue as before which is during my "for each row in" loop I have to specify a worksheet and when I go through the later if conditions I want to change the worksheet but then it gets out of the range so I guess to simplify my question:    How do I do "For each cell" in a range and as part of that loop have an if statement refer to a different range

Comment: It sounds like you aren't fully qualifying your worksheet object.  If you have multiple docs, you will need multiple Excel objects (ExcelA, ExcelB, ExcelC).  In my approach, you should only be processing a single worksheet at a time because you are storing the results in a data structure.  Keep in mind that using macro-generated VBA code through excel will leave you with a LOT of partially-qualified statements.  You need to go back and hook the .cell, .sheet, etc objects to the appropriate Excel object.